# PHP Upload Multiple Files with Different File Name but Common Folder

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to upload multiple files at once but have a solo form field to define the name of the column that will define the gallery name...
I tried different scripts and methods but the only one I've been successful with is this one, except I have to type the name of the gallery in each one, is there a way to do this?

Here's my HTML form

```
    <form action="php_multiple_upload2.php" method="post" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="galnom1"><input type="file" name="fileUpload1" ><br>
        <input type="text" name="galnom2"><input type="file" name="fileUpload2"><br>
        <input type="text" name="galnom3"><input type="file" name="fileUpload3"><br>
        <input type="text" name="galnom4"><input type="file" name="fileUpload4"><br>
        <input name="hdnLine" type="hidden" value="4">
        <input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Here's the PHP Code

```
    <?php
    include("../../cnf/cnctr.php");

    for($i=1;$i<=(int)($_POST["hdnLine"]);$i++)
    {
    if($_FILES["fileUpload".$i]["name"] != "")
      {
      if(copy($_FILES["fileUpload".$i]["tmp_name"],"img/".$_FILES["fileUpload".$i]["name"]))
        {
          $strSQL = "INSERT INTO galeria ";
          $strSQL .="(galnom,ttl) VALUES ('".$_POST["galnom".$i]."','".$_FILES["fileUpload".$i]["name"]."')";
          mysqli_query($fsn,$strSQL);
          echo "Copy/Upload ".$_FILES["fileUpload".$i]["name"]." completed.<br>";
        }
      }
    }
    echo "<br><a href='php_multiple_upload6.php'>View file</a>";
    mysqli_close($fsn);
    ?>
```

This is how I envision my html form:

```
    <form action="php_multiple_upload2.php" method="post" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="text" name="gallery_name"><br> <!-- Just one field to name the gallery -->
      <input type="file" name="fileUpload1" ><br>
      <input type="file" name="fileUpload2"><br>
      <input type="file" name="fileUpload3"><br>
      <input type="file" name="fileUpload4"><br>
      <input name="hdnLine" type="hidden" value="4">
      <input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

As always thanks for the help :)

Best Regards

Comment: Why don't you just reference that single field value from whatever index you're at in the loop? For instance, why do `$_POST["galnom".$i]` instead of `$_POST["galnom"]`?

Comment: Totally Right. That was it LOL.. Thank you so much Grant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the form like you envisioned it.

Just swap the line

```
$strSQL .="(galnom,ttl) VALUES ('".$_POST["galnom".$i]."','".$_FILES["fileUpload".$i]["name"]."')";
```

with this line:

```
$strSQL .="(galnom,ttl) VALUES ('".$_POST["gallery_name"]."','".$_FILES["fileUpload".$i]["name"]."')";
```

As a side note just in case: be aware that your SQL code is completely unsecured against SQL-injections

Comment: Thanks Grant and user1708452, Perfect solution.